# Are the walls of my garage closet load-bearing?

Tags: walls, garage, structural, load-bearing, closet

I am planning to remove this garage closet to make more room for our car. From looking at the framing it doesn't appear to be load bearing - which would obviously be very surprising considering it looks like just a little partition closet. But being a novice I want to ensure there's nothing I'm missing before demoing this. If there are any considerations I would greatly appreciate any thoughts. Thanks!

[image: red outline is generally closet walls]

[image: appears to be a little partition closet]

Comment: Looks like it's a major wiring nexus, so you'll have to be careful of that. Given the relationship to the garage door, I don't see removing it as giving the car any more room, since the car can't drive there anyway, but if you are removing the workbench and closet to make more room *around* the car, sure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that's a great point about the wiring. You can see a bunch of little scars in the sheetrock between the lawn mower and work bench where my car door hits. The garage is tight so you can hardly open the car door without that wall getting in the way. Perhaps I should just remove that wall to allow the car door to open freely so I could avoid any wiring issues?

Comment: @Navy247 - Technically speaking, it would be much easier to remove the car door. It's only held in place by a few screws.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe that it's load bearing for these reasons. I can't provide 100% certainty, however.

- There's no indication in the attic that the walls transfer load to the roof framing.
- You have a very conventional hand-framed garage roof. They almost never have mid-span bearing points unless there's a beam down the center.
- Bearing walls in the middle of a slab are also extremely rare in smaller residential garages.
- Normally you'd see footings and shorty blocks or a stub wall like on the perimeter if a load was expected there.

Be sure to repair the firewall (continuous drywall on wall and ceiling) as necessary after the closet is removed.